# How to use sum in MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sum, computation

This my code and I want a output like in the picture:

```
SELECT `test`.custinfo.CustID, OtherDeductionName AS DeductionName, sum(OtherDeductionAmount) as DeductionAmount FROM `db_payroll`.`tbl_otherdeductions`
LEFT JOIN `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll
ON `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll.OtherDeductionsID = `db_payroll`.tbl_otherdeductions.OtherDeductionsID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpayinternal on tbl_testpayinternal.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpay on tbl_testpay.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.custinfo on(CASE WHEN tbl_payroll.EmpID LIKE '%EX%' THEN `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpay.custid ELSE `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpayinternal.custid END)
WHERE `tbl_payroll`.`status` = 'Done' and `test`.custinfo.CustID = '00000008' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_start = '2022-11-14' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_end = '2022-11-28' 
AND `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.OtherDeductionsID <> ''
GROUP BY DeductionName
UNION
SELECT `test`.custinfo.CustID, StatutoryDeductionsName AS DeductionName, sum(StatutoryEE) as DeductionAmount FROM `test`.`tbl_statutorydeductions`
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_statutorydeductionstype
ON `test`.tbl_statutorydeductions.StatutoryDeductionsTypeID = `test`.tbl_statutorydeductionstype.StatutoryDeductionsTypeID
LEFT JOIN `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll
ON `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll.StatutoryDeductionsID = `test`.tbl_statutorydeductions.StatutoryDeductionsID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpayinternal on tbl_testpayinternal.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpay on tbl_testpay.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.custinfo on(CASE WHEN tbl_payroll.EmpID LIKE '%EX%' THEN `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpay.custid ELSE `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpayinternal.custid END)
WHERE `tbl_payroll`.`status` = 'Done' and `test`.custinfo.CustID = '00000008' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_start = '2022-11-14' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_end = '2022-11-28'
AND `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.StatutoryDeductionsID <> ''
GROUP BY DeductionName
UNION
SELECT `test`.custinfo.CustID, TypeOfLoan AS DeductionName, sum(AmortAmount) as DeductionAmount FROM `test`.`tbl_benamortloan`
LEFT JOIN `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll
ON `test`.tbl_benamortloan.IDno = `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll.EmpID AND `test`.tbl_benamortloan.CutOffID = `db_payroll`.tbl_payroll.CutOffID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpayinternal on tbl_testpayinternal.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.tbl_testpay on tbl_testpay.PRID = tbl_payroll.PRID
LEFT JOIN `test`.custinfo on(CASE WHEN tbl_payroll.EmpID LIKE '%EX%' THEN `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpay.custid ELSE `test`.custinfo.custid = `test`.tbl_testpayinternal.custid END)
WHERE  `tbl_payroll`.`status` = 'Done' and `test`.custinfo.CustID = '00000008' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_start = '2022-11-14' and `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.date_end = '2022-11-28'
AND `db_payroll`.`tbl_payroll`.LoanPaymentsID <> ''
GROUP BY DeductionName
ORDER BY DeductionName
```

[This is the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Mlb.png)

Can you help me with this

Comment: What have you tried and what result did you get so far?

Comment: First, what does this have to do with c#? Second, questions like this are difficult at best because we don't have your database and data. So I will also ask what results are you experiencing?

Comment: This is the result:
00000008     Car Loan Deduction   7500
00000008     INTERNET LOAD ALLOWANCE  -3500
00000008     LOAD ALLOWANCE    -12400
00000008     Mandatory Provident Fund   3645
00000008     PAG-IBIG - Salary Loan           3257.54
00000008     PAGIBIG      5800
00000008    PhilHealth   24226.370000000017
00000008    SSS      44505
00000008    SSS - Salary Loan    2500
00000008    TAX    30456.479999999996

i want to sum all the amount

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I see so far is a great big `UNION` query which will produce three concatenated groups of data, each one containing sums.  So maybe now all you need to do is something like:

```
SELECT SUM(DeductionAmount) FROM
(
  ..insert the text of your present query here..
)
```

Of course, this is the simplest example.

The key idea is this: "your present query" – textually included, within parentheses – is used as a ***subquery*** of a primary query that calculates the sum of all of the `DeductionAmount` columns now being provided by "your present query."  "Your present query" is the source of the rows seen by the outer-level one, and what you finally get is "the result of the outer-level one."

(Always separately *review* the result of your intended subquery, to be sure that it is consistent and correct, before wrapping it into an outer-level query. "Query bugs" can be hard to diagnose otherwise.)